# Existe algum famework PHP estilo JSF?

Tags: php, java, jquery, jsf, codeigniter

Sou programador Java e utilizo JSF nos projetos da empresa onde trabalho.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto pessoal e escolhi a linguagem PHP até pra aprender um pouco mais. O problema é que vi uma diferença enorme em relação a programar com o framework JSF. Por exemplo, junto com o JSF eu utilizo o Primefaces, dessa forma, quando preciso usar AJAX, eu faço tudo pelo framework sem a necessidade de escrever nenhuma função JavaScript. Na verdade não é necessário ter conhecimento algum em JavaScript, jQuery ou AJAX.

No PHP, estou usando o framework CodeIgniter e aí preciso parar a codificação PHP toda hora para criar funções JavaScript, criar funções em jQuery e requisições em AJAX, o que me toma muito tempo, além de ter que ficar parando as vezes para ver como algo funciona no jQuery.

Por isso gostaria de saber se existe algum framework no mesmo estilo para PHP.

Comment: Ao meu ver, valerá muito mais a pena você estudar JavaScript também.  Utilizar um framework já costuma ser uma ideia ruim - pois quase sempre o uso não é justificado. Depender completamente de um é uma péssima ideia. Se o que deseja fazer é função do JavaScript, você deverá escrever em JS. Se é do PHP, deverá escrever em PHP. Não misture as coisas.

Comment: Talvez o que chegue mais perto seja o YII.

Comment: Parece abandonado mas isso aqui pode ser um começo: https://github.com/asmblah/uniter (não que eu ache boa ideia, a qualidade do código que um transpilador vai produzir não se compara a um que vc mesmo escreva, to com o Anderson nessa)

Comment: Mas.. mas.. JSF não é framework.. É especificação!